# Alternative to inlining in C#?

Tags: c#, inline-code

I use the following statement to print the name of the current function (for example, an event handler) to the Output window in Visual Studio (2010):

```
Debug.Write(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name);
```

If I put this inside a utility function such as `DisplayFunctionName()`, instead of the parent function that calls it, what is displayed each time is "`DisplayFunctionName`" - no surprises there!

I know there is no inlining in C#, but is there another solution for this situation, short of using 'snippets', so as not to have to duplicate such statements?

Comment: "no inlining in C#?". wake up :-)

Comment: Yeah there is definitely inlining in C#. You don't get that kind of performance without inlining...

Comment: I meant inlining in the sense of "C++ type macros".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the [`CallerMemberNameAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute.aspx) to display the caller's name.

```
public void WriteDebug(string message, [CallerMemberName] string memberName = "")
{
    Debug.Write("[" + memberName + "] " + message);
}
```

There is also [`CallerLineNumberAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.callerlinenumberattribute.aspx) and [`CallerFilePathAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.callerfilepathattribute.aspx) which you can use to include this information for more diagnostics.  These attributes are [described in detail on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh534540.aspx). Combined with `[Conditional("DEBUG")]` on the method, you have the capability to provide a lot of information during debugging that is completely eliminated in a release build.

> I know there is no inlining in C#, but is there another solution for this situation, short of using 'snippets', so as not to have to duplicate such statements?

Note that this really has nothing to do directly with "inlining", as much as with getting the calling member's information for diagnostics.  That being said, the JIT definitely performs inlining when your code is run, which is one of the major reasons C# has decent performance.

This requires Visual Studio 2012, as it uses new compiler features in that release to function.

---

If you are using an older compiler, the other alternative is to use [`StackTrace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stacktrace.aspx) to pull out the stack trace information.  This has a fairly significant performance impact, however, so it's not something I'd use in a tight loop, at least not in a production environment, though its still functional for diagnostics during debugging.

```
string callingMethodName = (new StackTrace()).GetFrame(1).GetMethod().Name;
```

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh534540.aspx for some more detailed information.

Comment: Reed, thank you, +1.  I have Visual Studio 2010 and am using .NET 4.0 in my project.  CallerMemberName is not defined.  Will installing .NET 4.5 fix this situation?  Search results indicate it might not be possible with VS 2010.

Comment: @Sabuncu You'd need to use VS 2012 - it's a compiler feature.  You can still target .NET 4 (if you implement the attributes yourself), since it's purely a compiler feature, but it won't work in VS 2010.

Comment: @DeCaf: Thanks for the link, +1.  BTW, Reed references the same link in his 2nd paragraph.

Comment: Reed, thank you, both for the answer, and for being so polite about my mistake about "inlining" (what I meant was "macros").  No wonder you are ranked so high.

Comment: @Sabuncu Gave you another alternative for VS 2010/.NET 4